# Can't add users in SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to add user in Oracle Apex using SQL Workshop, SQL Commands option, but I am stuck here. Please someone help me with this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Error message is self-descriptive. You don't have permission to do that.

From [CREATE USER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8003.htm):

> You must have the **CREATE USER system privilege**.

I suggest to contact your DBA.

Comment: thankyou for reply but i dont know how to give system privilege through sql commands

Comment: @AlishManandhar You can't. Contact your DBA (I guess it is against some policies that regular user can create new users)

Answer (score 2):

Well, **database** users normally aren't created in Apex.

You should connect as a privileged user (if you didn't create any, that's SYS), but what would SYS do with Apex? Nothing, so - forget about it. I guess you didn't create a workspace and assigned SYS schema to it; at least, I've never heard that someone did that.

If you really want to create a database user, connect to SYS via SQL*Plus (or any other tool you use to access your Oracle database) and create it using the `CREATE USER` command.

On the other hand & in my opinion, user you need is created via Apex **admin** user (http://your-server/apex/apex_admin), i.e.

- workspace: internal
- username: admin
- password: you should know it

Then go to

- manage workspaces
- manage developers and **users**
- "Create user" button

Doing so, you'd create a *user* which can access your Apex applications, be a developer or even an administrator.